# .apk does not contain current icons - why?

Tags: android, apk

I'm new to Android & Eclipse. I have modified a small app by changing 2 of the icons among other things. When i test the app using emulators all works as expected. But, when i load the .apk file to an actual device, I get the old version of the app (old icons). How can i get the .apk file to use the current icons & code?

Answer (score 7):

How did you load the apk to your device? Using the console with adb make sure you have the reinstall option set. Otherwise check if eclipse told you, it has reinstalled the app (check the console in eclipse). Last thing to try: remove the old version on your device and install it again.

Comment: +1. It happened to me in the past. Removing the app from the device will make it work correctly.

Comment: ok .. i simply copied the apk file to my desktop & then dragged it to my phone (disk E:). 

i do not know how to invoke the console to type commands ... 

but upon futher research, found the resolution in the basic dev guide on android.com ... 

in eclipse one just needs to right click the project in the project-explorer window & select android tools > export signed project ... 

thanks for the suggestions!!

Comment: You can install the project with eclipse. Just right click on your project -> Run as -> Android Application -> Choose your connected device or emulator

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your device and your emulator are using different pixel densities (dpi), you replaced only one set and that's why old ones are taken.
You can:

- Check resources in
  `drawable-{l|m|h}dpi` folders and
  change them all
- Use same pixel
  density for emulator and device

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above answer you can also try to do this:
right click on your project in eclipse and goto android tools -> fix project properties.

M not very sure but tis might help.