# Playing sound in android

Tags: android, audio

mp=MediaPlayer.create(AlarmAlert.this, R.raw.clear);
mp.seekTo(0);
mp.start();

I use this code in my application, it's working when i try it in android emulator.
The application size is around 356KB in emulator.
But when i install the .apk in my phone there are o sound at all and the application size only around 50 KB.

What could be the problem? Installation problem??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an installation issue. How do you start/install your application? Take a look at this: [.apk does not contain current icons - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619053/apk-does-not-contain-current-icons-why/3619109#3619109)

Comment: i just uninstall the previous version and copy the new apk into my sdcard and install the application. I have uninstall it a few times but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you checked the content of the apk you installed? Just rename it to a .zip file and open it with a zip program. Can you find your sounds there?

Comment: yes i can find all my sounds in it.. It really strange when i try to install again only 56KB.. Is there any way we can check it when we already install it in the actual phone?

Comment: Try to install it directly with eclipse or adb. Don't forget to use the reinstall option. If you install the correct apk with adb, you should have all sounds ...

Comment: It working now.. My mistake the media volume is set silent.. Sorry for the trouble.. Thankss...